# Android - unregister ContentObserver defined in Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, contentobserver

I have a series of files to upload. Those are stored as entries in a Content Provider. Each entry also contains the percentage uploaded.

One activity displays a list of uploads, each file is an item with a ProgressBar to show the progress of the upload.

The way I am updating that progress bar is via a ContentObserver. Inside the CursorAdaptor I define a ContentObserver for each item and save it as the corresponding view's tag.

My problem now is I don't know when to unregister such ContentObservers. The only way I found was in the containing activity's `onDestroy()`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = mListView.getChildAt(i);
        final ContentObserver obs = (ContentObserver) v.getTag();
        if (obs != null) {
            getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(obs);
        }
    }
```

This is really, really awful. It introduces a dependency between the Adapter and the parent activity. On the other hand, non-unregistered ContentObservers can prevent the activity from being destroyed, introducing memory leaks.

Do you see a better way?

Comment: You should at least move your unregister loop to `onPause()` (and consequently, register it on `onResume()`) because you can not always anticipate when `onDestroy()` will be called or if system would kill your app without even calling it.

Comment: @shoe_rat, This is not true, it depends on in what lifecycle method you've done the registering of the ContentObserver. If you're unregistering in onPause while you've done the register call in onCreate, it will bomb on returning to that Activity multiple times (or you need additional checks). Also, what you're saying about the case when the app is killed by the system, is not true as a registered ContentObserver will be unregistered by the system if the system kills you (off course, otherwise you would eat up resources while being killed all the time).

Comment: Don't tie state to Views, Views come and go. Register one observer that receives an object holding all data, update that data to adapter, the call `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` on adapter.

Comment: S.D. is correct, use just one ContentObserver and don't tie views with state info

Answer (score 0):

If you have a content providor, you can use a CursorLoader instead.

https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

```
public class PhotoThumbnailFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...
}

/*
* Callback that's invoked when the system has initialized the Loader and
* is ready to start the query. This usually happens when initLoader() is
* called. The loaderID argument contains the ID value passed to the
* initLoader() call.
*/
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle)
{
    /*
     * Takes action based on the ID of the Loader that's being created
     */
    switch (loaderID) {
        case URL_LOADER:
            // Returns a new CursorLoader
            return new CursorLoader(
                        getActivity(),   // Parent activity context
                        mDataUrl,        // Table to query
                        mProjection,     // Projection to return
                        null,            // No selection clause
                        null,            // No selection arguments
                        null             // Default sort order
        );
        default:
            // An invalid id was passed in
            return null;
    }
}
```

You just define a cursor loader and  implement the callbacks and there is no need for a content observer. Works much better.